# Raid 5 Question

Tags: raid, adaptec

I have an HP ML150 Tower with Hot Plugs

It was configured with Raid 5 Running 2 Drives... One is a mirror

The first Drive in the Array failed.  We ordered a new one.

What happened was, the failed drive was unplugged live and replaced with the new one.

Now, two red lights appear, 1 from the failed drive and another from the third bay, there is no drive installed.

When we shutdown the server...

We went to adaptec menu via Ctrl-A

Then we checked the Drives...

Drive 0,0,0,0 - is redirected
       0,1 Compaq is Optimal
Drive 0,1,0,0 - is degraded
       1,2 is missing 
       1,1 Seagate Drive is Optimal

How do I fix this Raid and rebuild the redirected drive to the array?

Sorry for the noob question. I do hope anyone can help.

Comment: Are you certain it was setup as a RAID5 volume?  If so, then you are almost certainly SOL.  RAID5 requires 3 drives, if you have lost 2 of them, then your data is gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two disks mirroring the data this is called RAID1 even if your controller is capable to support RAID5 arrays.

You can find a description how to build a failed array on the Adaptec support pages. For example here: http://ask.adaptec.com/scripts/adaptec_tic.cfg/php.exe/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=14215&p_created=1130563445

It depends a bit on the specific controller and its BIOS version.